# Load required libraries with content using ajax

Tags: 8, ajax

So I created a form and and attached a Drupal library to it. From there I created a route that uses that form. Last a added a link that uses ajax to render that form.

For some reason when I look at the context that is rendered from that ajax request the ***/core/misc/vertical-tabs.js?v=8.2.6*** gets loaded onto the page along with the form content, but my attached custom library does not.

If I visit the page without using the ajax request both the ***/core/misc/vertical-tabs.js?v=8.2.6*** and my custom library load fine.

How can I get my custom library to load with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

So after playing with this for a while I figured out that Drupal only pulls in the js Assets through ajax, not the css. I guess this make sense on some level. But I figured I can easily pull in the necessary css in using js.